# build cross compiler mingw w64 gcc 4.8.2 on linux with winpthreads

Tags: gcc, build, pthreads, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I want to build a cross compiler mingw-w64 gcc in x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu to i686-w64-mingw32 with winphreads. From the document in the source package mingw-w64-v3.1.0/mingw-w64-doc, I know how to build cross gcc with win32 thread. However, I need to use c++11 thread, so I need to build cross gcc with posix thread. Moreover I know that mingw-w64 support posix thread in mingw-w64-v3.1.0/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads. Unfortunately, the above document does not explain how to build cross compiler mingw-w64 gcc.

Additional requirement, I need gcc, g++ gfortran and dwarf2 exception mode

As a result, I try the following procedure:

```
1 #!/bin/sh
2 
3 threads=8
4 
  #build binutils
5 wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.24.tar.bz2 -O - | tar -xj
6 cd binutils-2.24
7 mkdir build; cd $_
8 ../configure --prefix=$HOME/cross --with-sysroot=$HOME/cross --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib
9 make -j $threads; make check; make install-strip; cd ..; cd ..; rm -rf ~-
10 
   #install mingw-w64-headers
11 wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/mingw-w64-v3.1.0.tar.bz2/download -O - | tar -xj
12 cd mingw-w64-v3.1.0/mingw-w64-headers
13 mkdir build; cd $_
14 ../configure --prefix=$HOME/cross/i686-w64-mingw32
15 make install; cd $HOME
16 
17 ln -s $HOME/cross/i686-w64-mingw32 $HOME/cross/mingw
18 
   #build static gcc
19 wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2 -O - | tar -xj
20 cd gcc-4.8.2
21 mkdir build; cd $_
22 ../configure --prefix=$HOME/cross --with-sysroot=$HOME/cross --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-gmp=$HOME/gcc --with-mpfr=$HOME/gcc --with-mpc=$HOME/gcc --with-isl=$HOME/gcc --with-cloog=$HOME/gcc --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-dwarf2
23 make -j $threads all-gcc; make install-gcc
24 
25 export PATH=$HOME/cross/bin:$PATH
26 
   #build mingw-w64-crt
27 cd $HOME/mingw-w64-v3.1.0/mingw-w64-crt
28 mkdir build; cd $_
29 ../configure --prefix=$HOME/cross/i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=$HOME/cross --host=i686-w64-mingw32
30 make -j $threads; make install-strip
31 
   #build winpthreads
32 cd $HOME/mingw-w64-v3.1.0/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads
33 mkdir build; cd $_
34 ../configure --prefix=$HOME/cross/i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=$HOME/cross --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --enable-shared=no
35 make -j $threads; make install-strip
36 
   #build full gcc
37 cd $HOME/gcc-4.8.2/build
38 make -j $threads; make check; make install-strip
```

However, when I do the last step build full gcc, I get the error as the following:

```
 .libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o: In function `_gthread_mutex_lock':
 /home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:748: undefined reference to  `_imp__pthread_mutex_lock'
 .libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o: In function `_gthread_mutex_unlock':
 /home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:778: undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_unlock'
 .libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o: In function `_gthread_mutex_lock':
 /home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:748: undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_lock'
  .libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o: In function `_gthread_mutex_unlock':
  /home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:778: undefined reference to `_imp__pthread_mutex_unlock'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[5]: *** [libstdc++.la] Error 1
  make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/src'
  make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/src'
  make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3'
  make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3'
  make[1]: *** [all-target-libstdc++-v3] Error 2
  make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  config.status: executing libtool commands
  config.status: executing gstdint.h commands
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build'
  make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So, how to fix the problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show the actual command that is producing the error? Are you sure libpthread is in `$HOME/cross/i686-w64-mingw32/lib`? If the command shows it is linking to pthreads (it contains `-pthread` and/or `-lpthread`), can you execute it (from I believe `/home/cguo/gcc-4.8.2/build/i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/src`) and add the option `-v` to the command?